# Xcode constraint fix on landscape orientation

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a button at the bottom of my view which is constrained as intended on portrait, but when I rotate in simulator, it obviously retains the constraint and shows up before the rest of the content, which is supposed to precede it.  I simply don't know how to keep it at the bottom of the view in both orientations.

Bonus question: how to scroll down in simulator?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at size classes. They'll make it easy to lay out your button correctly. Try to read into the principles in this tutorial as it may not answer your specific scenario directly, but it will definitely give you a great start: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Comment: How have you constrained it?  Constraining the button's bottom edge to the views bottom margin would probably be the first place to start